# Is it okay to use "a lot of" with countable nouns

Tags: quantifiers, countable-nouns

Is it okay to use "a lot of" with countable nouns or is it still better to use "many" instead?

For example, how much is "He had many wives" better than "He had a lot of wives"?

Comment: Usages like *He had **many** wives* are very formal/dated. Not quite so much as ***numerous***, but in that general area.

Comment: There's not much in it, but one related expression that is definitely informal is "lots", as in "He had lots of wives".

Comment: @mathewb - I meant simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could. Many is better grammatically. The phrase "a lot" is used more in informal everyday speech.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine to substitute "a lot of" for "many" with countable objects:

> There are **many** ships out on the ocean today.
>   There are **a lot of** ships out on the ocean today.

As FumbleFingers points out in his comment, "many" can feel *formal* or [*dated*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dated), and "a lot of" is more *informal*.  It may be appropriate to use "many" with subjects that are already formal or dated.  Polygamy, for example, is a *dated* practice in much of the world, so "he had many wives" is appropriate, especially when talking about historical or biblical figures:

> King Solomon had **many** wives, supposedly more than 700.